# inserting in a concurrent hash map

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

The following piece of code does not work as expected. When I call put method in Does class the value in the concurrent hash map is associated with different instances of map. So what I am trying to do is multiple threads access the same map and insert a value for the same key. However if I add a synchronized keyword to the put method it works. What am I missing?

```
class Does implements Runnable {
    C2 c2;

    Does(C2 c2) {
        this.c2 = c2;
    }

    public void run() {
        c2.put("Hello");
    }

}

public class C2 {
    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        C2 c2 = new C2();
        new Thread(new Does(c2)).start();
        new Thread(new Does(c2)).start();
        new Thread(new Does(c2)).start();
        new Thread(new Does(c2)).start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<String> lu = c2.map.get("Hello");

        System.out.println(lu);
    }

    /**
     * @param string
     */
    public void put(String string) {
        if (map.containsKey(string)) {
            List<String> li = map.get(string);
            li.add("adding something");
        } else {
            List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
            li.add("adding something");
            map.put(string, li);
        }
    }

}
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: What isn't working as expected?  It's possible for all 4 threads to see that the map doesn't contain the key, and to then attempt to add it.

Comment: Yes but the put method is said to be thread safe for concurrent hash map. so I am guessing that should not be a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is not thread safe

```
public void put(String string) {
    if (map.containsKey(string)) {
        // anything can happen in another thread here
        List<String> li = map.get(string);
        // anything can happen in another thread here
        li.add("adding something");
    } else {
        // anything can happen in another thread here
        List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
        li.add("adding something");
        // anything can happen in another thread here
        map.put(string, li);
    }
```

In Java 8 you can use computeIfAbsent.

```
public void put(String string) {
    // all most thread safe.
    map.computeIfAbsent(string, k -> new ArrayList<>())
       .add("add something");
}
```

Note this is still not thread safe as the ArrayList is not thread safe, so what you need is

```
public void put(String string) {
    List<String> list = map.computeIfAbsent(string, k -> new ArrayList<>());
    synchronized(list) {
       list.add("add something");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting isn't the concurrent hash maps put method thread safe? Javadoc says that all operations for the concurrent hash map are thread safe

Comment: @Krish you don't understand what "thread safe" means.  Each individual operation is thread safe, but you are combining them in ways that lose the thread safety.

Comment: @LouisWasserman To be fair, this is something the designers of StringBuffer overlooked IMHO. SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe possibly *because* they used StringBuffer and expected it to do the thread safety for them.

Comment: @Krish as I noted in my answer, anything can happen at certain points.  This breaks thread safety.  Thread safety is not magic and how it is used matters.  Note: you can take code which is not thread safe and make it so, depending on how you use it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thank you for the answer. Did help.

Comment: hi @Krish , did the above solution of using concurrentHashMap, using computeIfAbsent and synchronizing on the List work for you?